# 'Suggested edits' notification displayed even though daily edit limit is reached

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, moderator-abilities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don’t show pending suggested edits to me after I run out of votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137074/dont-show-pending-suggested-edits-to-me-after-i-run-out-of-votes)

As a 10k user the 'suggested edits pending approval' notification is displayed to me:

[image]

This notification is displayed even when I've reached my daily edit review limit:

[image]

I suggest to *not* display this notification when I am not able to act on it (I can't even *see* the suggested edits).

Comment: Is this called *badge* or *the number of remaining review*?

Comment: @aditya I am not sure if this is called a 'badge'. Do you have a better name? Please suggest.

Comment: @Tichodroma, I would call it a "notification"

Comment: As I am newbie, I don't know more about it. But I think this is not a badge. We may call it number of remaining review.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Thanks, I've edited my question.