# Suggested edit count shown on toolbar when limit is reached

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, review, suggested-edits

Suggested edit count shown on toolbar when limit is reached.

[image]r

Here I have reached daily limit of 20 questions for suggested edits but there is indicator for that in tool bar. Also no indicator appears for `First Posts` or for `Low Quality Posts` or any other type. This indicator only appears for suggested edits.

[image]

Note there is no such indicator for `First Posts` or for `Low Quality Posts`. If it is a feature, it must be uniform for all types or not.

I know there is already a famous question [Don't show pending suggested edits to me after I run out of votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137074/dont-show-pending-suggested-edits-to-me-after-i-run-out-of-votes). But no satisfying answer. Also this is asked as feature but I think this is a bug.

Comment: There is no satisfying answer because it's a feature request that hasn't been implemented or refused by SE. That doesn't make this question any less of a duplicate though.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards, I know this question is asked but no satisfying answer is there. Also want to add there is no such indicator for all other types. If it is there for suggested edit, it must be for all other types as well for uniformity....

Comment: If you want to add the feature for the other queues why not create a feature request to do so? Don't lump it into another question.

Comment: I don't want add the feature, I want this to be removed when I have reached the limit.

Comment: I know question is duplicate but it has no satisfactory answer there. Answers suggested there must be correction in this functionality or they suggest new feature but its never implemented or recognized by those answers...