# Why "suggested edit pending approval" notification is there even after I have reached the daily limit

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, top-bar

First of all, I have gone through [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137074/dont-show-pending-suggested-edits-to-me-after-i-run-out-of-votes). But I am not satisfied, and I do agree with **"Reviewing is important to keep the quality of questions and answers high"**.

My question is, why that notification is there even after I ran out of the daily limit. I mean can't they disable that if user has reached the limit?

What is the point of having such a notification on the top-bar if we have nothing to do? Is there any option to disable that?

Comment: @RagingBull Stating that you've read the other question doesn't make you immune from duplication if that question says the *exact same thing* as you are.